# Connection Pools and Billed-Hourly Instances

Tags: javascript, connection-pooling, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm trying to better understand how connection pools work in `knex`.

In the future, I'd like to deploy my application to a PaaS with a billed-hourly MySQL datastore. My concern is that using a connection pool (as `knex` does) will cause me to keep connections open to my datastore that I no longer need, thereby costing me instance hours.

Therefore, my question is: does `knex` automatically remove connections in the pool after they are not used for an extended period of time? Further, if it's the case that there is no scale-down of connections, what should I do to make sure that I'm not being charged for unused instance hours when all connections in the pool are inactive?

I imagine that, if there is no automatic scale-down, I'll need to be able to access the active connections in the pool in order to ensure I know when all connections are inactive, and then destroy the pool. Unfortunately, I'm not entirely sure how to do that (I couldn't find it in the documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knex uses Pool2 for pooling with a default of 2 minimum connections open (see [knex.js pooling](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-pooling)). So your worries are valid if using those defaults.

To change the behavior try something like:

```
var knex = require('knex')({ 
  client: '<your driver, mysql?>', 
  connection: { <your connection parameters> }, 
  pool: { 
    min: 0 /* no connections if idle */, 
    idleTimeout: 10*1000 /* 10 secs idle connections are closed */ 
}});
```